# Rails: Passing An Association As A Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, parameter-passing

In my model, I have several associations, such as:

```
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, :through => :posts
belongs_to :user
```

I also have a method that I want to gather associated objects, as specified by a parameter:

```
def selected_associations(*associations)
  associations.collect{|association| self.association}
end
```

The thing is, how do I pass in `*associations`? I've tried doing so with an array of symbols:

```
self.selected_associations([:posts, :comments])
```

But that doesn't work. Neither does passing them in as strings. Perhaps I'm not approaching this the right way?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe you could provide an example of what you would like `self.selected_associations` to return...

Comment: A collection of the associated objects, such as `[self.posts, self.comments]`. To be fair, this is an oversimplified example of what I'm doing. I'm just trying to get at the heart of the question. Namely, is it possible to get an association with a variable such as `self.association` instead of an explicit call to that association such as `self.posts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points here.

First of all, `self.association` won't work. You need change this to:

```
def selected_associations(*associations)
  associations.collect{|association| self.public_send(association)}
end
```

About method call, you need to pass as hash.

```
selected_associations :posts, :comments
```

Best.